# Sonar Runner 404 localhost

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I'm trying to get Sonar working locally on an OS X box to do some proof of concept work, I've downloaded the following:

**Sonar Qube:** 4.5.6

**Sonar Runner:** 2.4

Sonar Qube is configured as:

```
sonar.web.host=localhost
sonar.web.context=/sonar
sonar.web.port=9000
```

When I try and use Sonar Runner with one of the example projects I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Fail to request server version
ERROR: Caused by: Status returned by url : 'http://localhost:9000/sonar/api/server/version' is invalid : 404
```

If I copy and paste the URL from the console into the browser then the page loads (displaying 4.5.6).

What could be causing the script to receive a 404?

The box is behind a proxy but nothing should be trying to get to the outside world

**UPDATE:**
Changing the configuration from localhost to using the machines IP address produces a timeout rather than a 404, everything still works fine through the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turned out my problem was that the `JVM` wasn't using the proxy settings of my machine, I had to add the following to the `Sonar` runner script.

```
SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=my.local.host"
```

Comment: Where did you put this configuration SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that HTTP queries from `sonar-runner` are routed based on system proxy settings, while your browsers may use their own proxy settings.

Go check the system-wide setting:

> System Preferences/Network/Advanced/Proxies/Bypass proxy settings for these Hosts & Domains

And make sure that localhost/127.0.0.1 is in there.

Answer (score 0):

```
Actually, it means the port cannot be started. Just locate the sonar.properties file and modify the port configuration.
For example, change the configuration to the following:
sonar.web.host=127.0.0.1
sonar.web.context=/sonar
sonar.web.port=11000
sonar.search.port=11001
```

After a successful start, you will be able to access this webpage. Please note the configuration of your sonar.web.context as well.
http://localhost:11000/sonar/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).