# Jenkins SonarQube Scanner Behind a Proxy

Tags: jenkins, proxy, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We have a Jenkins server setup in our datacenter and behind our proxy.
We're trying to have that machine run SonarQube Scanner on a repo and publish the results out to a SonarQube server outside our network (in AWS).

The job starts up Sonar Scanner properly but then fails when trying to connect to our SonarQube server:

`22:12:31.612 DEBUG: keyStore is :
22:12:31.613 DEBUG: keyStore type is : jks
22:12:31.613 DEBUG: keyStore provider is :
22:12:31.613 DEBUG: init keystore
22:12:31.613 DEBUG: init keymanager of type SunX509
22:12:31.682 INFO: User cache: /zdata/jenkins/.sonar/cache
22:12:31.683 DEBUG: Extract sonar-scanner-api-batch in temp...
22:12:31.687 DEBUG: Get bootstrap index...
22:12:31.687 DEBUG: Download: http://my-sq-server.com/batch/index
22:12:31.713 ERROR: SonarQube server [http://my-sq-server.com] can not be reached`

I read [Sonar Runner Behind a Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34544428/sonar-runner-behind-a-proxy) and tried putting those values in the JVM options section and the Additional Options sections but they don't seem to make any difference.

To troubleshoot this a little I added a simple `curl` step to the Jenkins job just through a bash script and had that hit the same server and that worked fine.

I'm sure I'm just missing a tiny little detail here but I'm new to SQ and don't quite know where else to look.

**UPDATE**

The current output is showing this:

`/zdata/jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/scanner-3.0.1.733/bin/sonar-scanner -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.hostname.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -e -Dsonar.host.url=http://my-sonarqube-server.com ******** -Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 -Dsonar.sources=. -Dsonar.language=js -Dsonar.exclusions=__tests__/**,**/node_modules/**,coverage/** -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.0 -Dsonar.projectKey=repo-key -Dsonar.verbose=true -Dsonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath=coverage/lcov.info -Dsonar.tests=__tests__ "-Dsonar.projectName=Project Name" -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=/zdata/jenkins/workspace/my-project`

Comment: Can you precise the version of the Scanner you are using? We made several improvements around proxy in recent versions.

Comment: 3.0.1.733 (and SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins 2.6.1)

Comment: Try to pass  `-Djavax.net.debug=all` to the JVM options. This will log network related operations. This is extremely verbose, but should help to understand what happens. If you don't manage to "read" the output I suggest you create a new thread on the SonarQube user group. SO is not appropriate to investigate problems.

Answer (score 3):

Check if your proxy requires authentication: you might have to add

```
-Dhttp.proxyUser=username -Dhttp.proxyPassword=password
```

Make sure your proxy is reference as the proxy server name, without `http://`:

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxy (not -Dhttp.proxyHost=http://myproxy)
```

Comment: I added the current log output from Jenkins.  Our proxy does not require authentication.